# How do you currently logged in user object when using restangular?

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have tried this but it seems not to be working what am I missing

```
Restangular.one('authenticated_user').get().then(function(response){
    return response;
}, function(response){
    return response;
});
```

Comment: i meant an object containing information about currently logged in user. Hope its clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

```
function getAuthenticatedUser(onSuccess, onError){

        Restangular.one('authenticated_user').get().then(function(response){

            onSuccess(response.user);

        }, function(response){

            onError(response);

        });

    }
```